# jsTree not all nodes expanded are reopened after refresh even if saved correctly to cookies

Tags: json, jstree

To reproduce the problem:

- go to http://www.jstree.com/demo page and scroll down to "PHP & mySQL demo + event order" demo
- add tree folders, each with one subfolder, each subfolder with one file
- make sure that every folder and subfolder is expanded, and that there are more than two folders expanded
- hit refresh. Only the first two folders expanded are expanded, the others are closed again, even though all the folders were expanded

I have the same exact problem in my application. I have stepped through
the java script code with the debugger and saw that the cookies are saved and contain the ids of all the expanded nodes before the refresh but somehow only the
first two nodes are used, the rest are discarded and cleared from the cookie.

Can you think of a solution?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Lorant